# Is $\sin(1/x)$ Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Is the function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ Lebesgue integrable on $(0,1]$?

I know that, as $f$ is continuous on the set, it is a measurable function. However, I'm stumped on how to go on. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is even Riemann integrable.

Comment: Does Riemann imply Lebesgue on finite intervals then?

Comment: [Yes](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/291020/18880)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $|f(x)|\le1$ for all $x\in(0,1]$, so $f$ is uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed something so obvious.

Comment: What does it mean for a single function to be uniformly bounded?

Comment: Yeah alright, "bounded" was probably enough.