# Are upper and lower Lebesgue integrals equal for every $f$?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Is it true that lower and upper Lebesgue integrals are equal for every Lebesgue integrable function?

If you look [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/245a-notes-2-the-lebesgue-integral/) you will see that:

> One nice feature of measurable functions is that the lower and upper
>   Lebesgue integrals can match, if one also assumes some boundedness.
>
> Exercise 11 Let $f: {\bf R}^d \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ be measurable,
>   bounded, and vanishing outside of a set of finite measure. Show that
>   the lower and upper Lebesgue integrals of $f$ agree. (Hint: use
>   Exercise 4.) There is a converse to this statement, but we will defer
>   it to later notes. What happens if $f$ is allowed to be unbounded, or
>   is not supported inside a set of finite measure?

So... what happens if $f$ is unbounded? Are upper and lower integrals equal? One person in the comments suggested it's true for unbounded functions as well (but he didn't provide a proof).

Lebesgue defines area - then it's reasonable to expect that approximation of the area 'from above' and 'from below' should yield the same value (it's equivalent to saying that upper and lower Lebesgue integrals are equal - it would be nice if it was true).

Based on the comments to my question, I'd say it depends on the definition of simple function - whether we want it to take finite valus, or countably many values. But, according on the definition in prof. Tao's article, what would be the correct answer to question raised in Exercise 11, quoted above?

Apparently there are examples of Riemann integrable functions, whose upper Lebesgue integral doesn't equal (lower) Lebesgue integrals. But it's true that if both Riemann and Lebesgue integrals exist, they are equal.

Comment: Using the definitions in the book, I don't see how upper Lebesgue integrals could exist for an unbounded function.  What simple function could dominate an unbounded function?  What would be the finite set of values?

Comment: Rather, the upper integral would be infinite, because that's the infinimum of the empty set of simple functions which dominate.  But not all unbounded functions have infinite Lesbesgue integral.

Comment: @Gaffney you're saying 'what simple function could dominate an unbounded function'? Well, can't we just define a simple function which is greater or equal than $f$ for all $x$?

Comment: If $f$ is unbounded, then all the "dominant" simple functions would be infinite on a set of non-zero measure. All the "dominant" integrals would then be infinite.

Comment: @user4205580: no.  The link you provide links through to wikipedia for the definition of simple function, which is defined as a _real-valued_ function.  This means that it must be finite everywhere (to allow $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ we talk of the _extended reals_).  So a simple function is finite everywhere, which means it cannot dominate an unbounded function at points where that function is unbounded.

Comment: As far as I remember, if the function is bounded, then the "upper" lebesgue integral coincides with the conventional one. If the function is not bounded, the "upper" lebesgue integral is not well-defined.

Comment: @user4205580 A simple function can take only a finite number of values.  If you made a list of these values, it would be possible to find an $x$ for which $f(x)$ is bigger than every value on that list.  Because as postmortes points out the values in that list would have to all be finite.

Comment: If you define a simple function as a function which takes on only a countable number of values, then you can find an upper bound with finite integral, but that would be a definition of simple that the book doesn't use.

Comment: Sigh! I've never understood what Lebesgue integration is, or what it is good for, and nevertheless have the feeling that I haven't missed anything worthwhile in mathematics, but _I don't want to spoil the party so I'll go_.

Answer (score 1):

According to the definition 1 simple functions are measurable functions that take only afinite number of values.

take the function $f:x\mapsto\frac{1}{x^2}\mathbb{1}_{[1;+\infty[}$ (from R to R) and take $g$ a simple function such that $g\geq f $. We call $\alpha$ the smallest non zero value of $g$ (which exists because $g$ only take a finite number of values), since $g\geq f$ we know that for every $x\geq 1$ we have $g(x)>0$ and so $g(x)\geq \alpha$. Thus $\int g \mathrm d\lambda\geq \alpha \cdot m([1;+\infty[)=+\infty$. So the upper Lebesgue integral of $f$ is infinite whereas the lower lebesgue integral of $f$ is equal to the Riemann integral of $f$, which is finite.

The same thing can be done with $f : x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\mathbb{1}_{]0;1]} $.

This two counterexample cease to work if we allow a simple function to take a countable number of values.

EDIT (in response to the edit of the question) :

First, what you say is not correct, the functions i've used in my example are not riemann integrable strictly speaking. If you use Riemann integration it'll be "improper" integrals. Usually (but it might varie a little between different autors) Riemann integral deal only with bounded functions with compact support, for which upper and lower lebesgue integral are equal (and for which riemann and lesbesgue integral are equal)

Second and last, in the article you linked Tao define the unsigned Lebesgue integral as the lower unsigned lebesgue integral, with no mention of the upper lebesgue integral. So according to the definition choosed the Lebesgue unsigned integral exists even if the lower and upper integral are not equal.

Comment: Just to make sure - if $f$ is Riemann integrable, then its Lebesgue integral is equal to Riemann integral, and also its upper Lebesgue integral?

Comment: Yes, because riemann integrable means that your function has a compact support and is bounded.

Comment: @Renart I wonder how the proof of the exercise goes using boundedness and compact support?

Comment: @ I understand the counter example, but how to prove the original statement in the exercise?

Answer (score 0):

The upper and lower integrals can disagree on a set of Lebesgue measure 0, i.e "$\lambda$ -  a. e."

Comment: Some more detail would improve this answer!