# Doubt regarding definition of integral for positive measurable functions.

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am starting to study some Measurement Theory following the book [Measures, Integrals and Martingales](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1316620247) and I have a doubt regarding the definition of integral that the author provides.

First he defines the integral for simple functions as 
$$I_{\mu}(f):=\sum_{j=0}^M y_j \mu(A_j)$$
(where $f$ is a simple function, ${A_j}\in \sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is a measure).

Then using the previous one he defines (Definition $9.4$) the $\mu$-integral of a positive measurable function as:

> $$\int u \, d\mu:=\sup\{I_{\mu}(g):g\leq u, g \text{ is simple}\}$$

I am not really familiar with this definition, but this looks pretty much as the "lower integral" on Riemann's definition.

Actually I was expecting to see also a sort of "upper integral" too, but nothing else was stated.

Does this have to do with the fact that the function $u$ is measurable (by assumption)?
If not, why don't we require both the upper and the lower integral to coincide? 
Maybe this is a straightforward application of some well-known result that I am not aware of, but as I said this is my first approach to measure theory. 
Thanks in advance

---

> EDIT: Could this be because we know that any measurable function is
>   the point-wise limit of simple functions, so we don't actually need to
>   calculate the upper integral. We can ‘inscribe’ simple functions 
>   below the graph of $u$ and exhaust the area?

Comment: Essentially the same question is addressed here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476659/are-upper-and-lower-lebesgue-integrals-equal-for-every-f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the idea is to measure the area below the graph using simple functions which approximate the function from below. There is a general staatement which shows that any measurable function $u \geq 0$ can be approximated from below by simple functions (in the book you are using, this result is called Sombrero lemma), and therefore this is a reasonable approach.

If you, say, have a bounded function $u \geq 0$, then you can use the same idea as in the proof of the Sombrero lemma to construct a sequence of (uniformly bounded) simple functions $g_j$, $j \geq 1$, such that $g_j \downarrow u$ and the integrals will converge, i.e. $\int g_j \, d\mu \to \int u \, d\mu$. This shows that the "upper integral" and "lower integral" coincide in this case.

For unbounded functions it is typically impossible to get an approximation from above by simple functions; that's, in fact, one of **the** reasons to define the integral as an "lower integral". The point is that any real-valued simple function $g$ is bounded. Therefore, we can in general not find simple functions $g$ with $g \geq u$ for $u$ unbounded. In principle, we might allow $g$ to take the value $+\infty$ but if this happens on a set of positive measure, then the integral $\int g \, d\mu$ will be infinite. If we would use upper integrals to define the integral $\int u \, d\mu$, then this would mean that only bounded functions were integrable - and that's hardly what we want to have.

Comment: Very clear explanation, I like the fact that you gave a concise reason why we use the lower integral! Thanks

Comment: @RScrlli Thank you; you are welcome.

Comment: One more question, in principle the Reimann integral is defined for bounded functions in bounded intervals. On your last sentence you pointed out that not only bounded functions are integrable (w.r.t a measure), and furthermore a measurable function can be defined on $\mathbb{R}$ which is clearly not bounded, so, is the integration wrt a measure closer to the concept of improper Reimann integral?

Comment: @RScrlli Well, the improper Riemann integral is a bit "closer" in the sense that it allows for functions with unbounded support (.... as Lebesgue integral does). Apart from that, the improper Riemann integral has similar pitfalls as the (proper) Riemann integral.