# How to prove that a function is in fact $L_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm working on two problems where I need to interchange the limit and integral signs, so I want to evoke Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. I now know that the functions I have chosen do indeed dominate, but is there a way to show that the dominating functions are in fact Lebesgue integrable? (I don't want to calculate their integrals...)

One of the functions I am trying to show are Lebesgue integrable are: $\dfrac{1}
{1+x^2}$ over the domain $[0,\infty)$

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: For $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$, I think you should just go ahead and compute the integral.  It's easy, just basic calculus.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was thinking; was just wondering if there was a more "theoretical way" I guess. Thanks!

Comment: It's non-negative, so you just need to bound it, i.e. show it's integral is finite. What's your domain?

Comment: The domain is from $[0,\infty)$

Comment: Then a more portable method would be to split the domain like this: $\int_0^{\infty} \tfrac{1}{1+x^2} = \int_0^1 \tfrac{1}{1+x^2} + \int_1^{\infty} \tfrac{1}{1+x^2}$. The first term is at most 1. The second is at most $\int_1^{\infty} x^{-2}$. This is finite, too, and is considered a quotable truth so that in future you will write or think that "$\tfrac{1}{1+x^2}$ is bounded near zero and $\leq Cx^{-2}$ for large x".

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for more "theoretical" approach, maybe this is something for you.

We have 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x \rightarrow \pm \infty}\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}=1
\end{equation}
and therefore
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq c \ \frac{1}{x^2},
\end{equation}
for $|x| \geq a$ and suitable constants $a$ and $c$.
On the (compact) interval $ [ -a,a ]$ we can bound the (continuous) function by a constant. And outside of the interval it is just $\frac{1}{x^2}$ scaled by a constant which is known to be integrable outside an interval around zero.

In this case it is quite easy to see what $c$ and $a$ are (even without the limit argument, as pointed out by David C. Ullrich) - but this approach may work in "more complicated" cases: The function considered is continuous and behaves like a integrable function when $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Comment: This is imo the way to look at it. Surely that $c\frac1x$ was a typo? You might note that the inequality $1/(1+x^2)\le 1/x^2$ is obvious, no need for that limit argument.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the evaluation of the improper integral is just an application of the Monotone Convergence Theorem to $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}\chi _{[0,n)}(x)$

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to answer the general question you ask; too general.

For the specific example of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ being in $L^1([0,\infty))$ you could give a detailed proof as below. **Note** that what's below is much more detail than anyone would actually write, except in a first-semester measure theory class. Also **note** that I'm not going to use that $\arctan$ thing; I'm not going to calculate the integral exactly. What I do below is better because the sort of thing I do below would also let you show that a function like $1/(1+x^6)$ was Lebesgue integrable, when you don't know an explicit antiderivative. So:

First, $f$ is measurable since it's continuous.

Now $$\int_0^1 f\le\int_0^1 1=1.$$

For every $A$ with $1<A<\infty$ the theorem that the Lebesgue integral of a continuous function on $[a,b]$ equals its Riemann integral shows that $$\int_1^A f\le\int_1^A\frac{dt}{t^2}=1-A^{-1}\le 1.$$So the Monotone Convergence Theorem shows that $$\int_1^\infty f\le 1.$$

(You should think about how I'm applying MCT here; what increasing sequence of positive functions am I talking about?)

So $\int_0^\infty|f|=\int_0^\infty f\le 1+1<\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

If we're talking about $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, then we should show that the integral is finite (it is).

Also, recall that this neat function is also Riemann integrable - that means that it is Lebesgue integrable. Check [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291020/does-riemann-integrable-imply-lebesgue-integrable) out.

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. My domain is $[0,\infty)$, so that means I can't necessarily say that R. integrability implies L. integrability right?

Comment: No, it still holds, but the integral of this function over $[0, \infty )$ is still finite.