# Proof that $f$ is Riemann integrable without Lebesgue criteria

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Consider $f$ and let it be Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ and Lebesgue measurable on $[0,1]$. Show that function is Lebesgue integrable (without Lebesgue-theorem).

I thought about considering *lower* and *upper* Daurboux sums $M(x)$ and $m(x)$ and we know that $m(x) \le f(x) \le M(x)$ , but I don't use measurability of $f$. Also we know that Riemann integrable function is bounded, maybe it will be enough for Lebesgue integrability?

Any hints?

Comment: Reimann integrable (roughly speaking) implies Lebesgue measurable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291020/does-riemann-integrable-imply-lebesgue-integrable

Comment: @parsiad yes, I understand that. 
But in my question I don't want to use Lebesgue theorem (if function is **properly** Riemann integrable , then it's Lebesgue integrable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is bounded, we may shift it so that $f\geq0$.
Since $f$ is Riemann-integrable, there is a sequence of step functions $h^+_k,h^-_k:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ so that $0\leq h^-_k\leq f\leq h^+_k$ and
$$
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1h^+_k
=
\lim_{k\to\infty}\int_0^1h^-_k
.
$$
These are integrals of step functions and can be defined as finite sums.
The limit is the Riemann integral $R$ of $f$.

The Lebesgue integral $L$ of $f$ is the supremum of all $\int w$ for $0\leq w\leq f$ with $w$ simple.
Since $w\leq f\leq h_k^+$, we know that $\int w\leq\int h_k^+$ for every $k$.
But $\int h_k^+\to R$, so in fact $\int w\leq R$ and consequently $L\leq R$.

This shows that he Lebesgue integral is finite and therefore $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.
To get the value of the Lebesgue integral, simply use the step function $h_k^-$ as a simple function in the definition to see that in fact $L=R$.