# Can a function be well-defined on an integral of $\mathbb{R}$ but not Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: integration, functions, lebesgue-integral

I was thinking about a comment on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2723721/indefinite-integrals-of-xx-sinx-x-and-relation-to-elementary-integrals/2723769#2723769), and how some functions are not Riemann integrable but *are* Lebesgue integrable. But are there any functions which are **defined everywhere** in an interval of $\mathbb{R}$ but are **not Lebesgue integrable**? In other words, does it make sense for a function to have no antiderivative by Lebesgue integration?

For example, is there an $f(t)$ that satisfies the properties of the third section below:

$$\begin{aligned}
&\quad\quad\text{$\sin(t)$ defined everywhere ✓}\\
\int_0^x \sin(t) \;\mathrm{d}t :&\quad\quad\text{Riemann integrable ✓} \\
&\quad\quad\text{Lebesgue integrable ✓} \\
\\
\hline
\\
&\quad\quad\text{$I_\mathbb{Q}(t)$ defined everywhere in interval ✓}\\
\int_0^x I_\mathbb{Q}(t) \;\mathrm{d}t :&\quad\quad\text{Riemann integrable ✗} \\
&\quad\quad\text{Lebesgue integrable ✓} \\
\\
\hline
\\
&\quad\quad\text{$f(t)$ defined everywhere in interval ✓}\\
\int_0^x f(t) \;\mathrm{d}t :&\quad\quad\text{Riemann integrable ✗} \\
&\quad\quad\text{Lebesgue integrable ✗} \\
\end{aligned}$$

Where $I_\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is the Dirichlet function.

Comment: I suspect an approach like this could work: partition $[0, 1]$ into countably many translations $V_1, V_2, \ldots$ of the immeasurable Vitali set (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137949/the-construction-of-a-vitali-set), and then define $f(x) = n$ wherever $x \in V_n$.

Comment: Do you want a function that is not Lebesgue integrable (if so, over what set?) or do you want a function that is nowhere Lebesgue integrable? If the latter, then you may want to say what you mean by "nowhere Lebesgue integrable" (i.e. not Lebesgue integrable over any open interval, not Lebesgue integrable over any nonempty open set, not Lebesgue integrable over any Borel set with positive Lebesgue measure, not Lebesgue integrable over any Lebesgue measurable set with positive Lebesgue measure, etc.). Yes, I know the various equivalences, but is this also part of your question?

Comment: Hi, @DaveL.Renfro. I wanted a function that wasn't Lebesgue integrable over some interval on the real line. I hadn't considered your points about what set the integral's over so I'll have to read up on that and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @Jam, then my example would work. This function is not integrable over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Oleg I'll give you the bounty when the minimum time's elapsed.

Comment: the characteristic function of a Bernstein set would be "nowhere Lebesgue integrable". https://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/bernstein-set/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_set and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/169714/whats-application-of-bernstein-set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, let $A\subset[0,1]$ be a set which is not measurable with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Let $f(t)=I_A(t)$. Then $f$ is defined everywhere in the interval $[0,1]$, but is neither Riemann nor Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: We need "integrable nowhere" in the sense that $\int_A |f| dx$ is undefined for each Lebesgue measurable set $A$ with $|A|>0$,