# On the horizontal integration of the Lebesgue integral

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, riemann-sum

I'm studying Lebesgue integral and its difference with respect to the Riemann one.
I'm reading that the key difference (at least graphically speaking) is that the first slices the function horizontally, while the latter works vertically. This concept is summed in the figure.

[image]

In Riemann integral definition the graphical procedure is trivial, as we have
$$\int f(x) dx= \lim_{x\to+\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) (x_i-x_{i-1})$$
and so the $(x_i-x_{i-1})$ is the basis of my rectangle while $f(x_i)$ is the height.

In Lebesgue we have (following Rudin pg.19)
$$\int_E f d\mu = \sup\int_E s d\mu = \sup \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \mu(A_i \bigcap E_i)$$
but I can't get in any formulation of the Lebesgue integral which is the basis of the rectangle and which is the height, also because in Lebesgue there is no $x$ in the integral.

I think that $d\mu$ in this case become the small height of each rectangle but I don't figure out how $f$, which was the height in Riemann, now could become the basis. Vice versa, if $d\mu$ is still the basis and I integrate according to the variation of $\mu$, this technique does not seem to cut *horizontally* the function.

What is the idea behind this horizontal integration?
I read [Lebesgue integral basics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/lebesgue-integral-basics) a possible answer but still I can't figured out a completely clear explanation.

Any suggestion is really appreciated.

Comment: The direct definition doesn't imply this at all. I hope this would stop being perpetuated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, $\mu$ would represent the base of the rectangle. But that's not the important part. The important part is the definition of the set you are taking the measure of.

Let's look at your image. Imagine each rectangle is height of exactly 1 unit. We might define the sets like this:

$$E_n = \{ x : n \le f(x) < n+1\}.$$

We look at the measure of each of these sets.

For $n = 1$, the set of numbers in $E_1$ is exactly the bottom-most rectangle projected onto the $x$-axis. It has measure $\mu(E_1)$. The second rectangle from the bottom is $E_2$, and so forth.

Each of these rectangles has height $1$, so we can approximate the integral as

$$\int f\, d\mu = \sum 1\cdot \mu(E_n).$$

What might be stumbling you up is that you are expecting that the *location* of those horizontal slices, as shown in the picture, is somehow embedded within the sum. It is not; rather, the rectangles are essentially sets, pulled upwards by steps of $1$.

Of course, we need not choose height $1$, and it need not be uniform. Instead, we can choose height $a_n$.

Comment: So if I got you point, Lebesgue says: sum the rectangles of height $a_n$ (which is the marginal vertical increment, in this sense the slicing is embedded) whose basis is represented by the corresponding length (measure) of the interval on the $x$ axis.

Comment: This is an old post but .... yes, I think you've got it since you phrased it that way, and I think you've also got it that the red figure you cited from wiki is wrong or misleading at best.

Comment: The correct $E_n$'s that'd make this answer sensible are $E_n := \{x : f(x)\ge n\}$.

Answer (score 8):

The fact that the Lebesgue integral "works vertically" means that we start by partitioning the range of the function (instead of the domain) and drawing horizontal lines from these points. But the final rectangles are not horizontal in the sense of your red figure.

Therefore, you didn't understand it because there is no natural connection between the usual definition and your red figure. Actually, as the $E_i$ are not apparent, the important fact that they aren't intervals, aren't lengths or heights and, eventually, are very complicated (which motivates the definition of measurable sets and measurable functions) is completely lost in the  figure. By the way, the fact that this figure is so wrong that it should be removed from the Wikipedia's article is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia_talk:WikiProject_Mathematics/Archive_26#Mathematical_eyes_sought).

I suggest you take a look at the appropriate geometric interpretation as, for example, in Preface of [Mikusinski's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=AX0ECAAAQBAJ&pg=PR5&dq=%22Intuitively,+the+difference+between+various+approaches+to+integration+may+be+brought+out+by+the+following+story+on+shoemakers.%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPo5CIxOnoAhXVH7kGHWevDD0Q6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Intuitively%2C%20the%20difference%20between%20various%20approaches%20to%20integration%20may%20be%20brought%20out%20by%20the%20following%20story%20on%20shoemakers.%22&f=false) or in Chapter 2 of [Folland's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wI4fAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT56&lpg=PT56&dq=%22A+few+remarks+comparing+the+construction+of+the+Lebesgue+and+Riemann+integrals+may+be+helpful.%22&source=bl&ots=m1eodPBitI&sig=ACfU3U0fynoAuXzpYKcsuovy6q4oXCq8vw&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjq8Ma2xOnoAhWuH7kGHVf6AjoQ6AEwAHoECAQQLA#v=onepage&q=%22A%20few%20remarks%20comparing%20the%20construction%20of%20the%20Lebesgue%20and%20Riemann%20integrals%20may%20be%20helpful.%22&f=false). As explained in these texts, the correct picture would have the following form ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RandLintegral.png)):

[image]

Of course, this picture can also illustrate an approximation for the Riemann integral. This happens because the Lebesgue integrable functions that have "nice figures" are also Riemann integrable. So, what really matters is not the final form of the figure (as suggested by the original red figure), but the way it is constructed (which is explained in the cited books).

Comment: Thank you. I was going insane trying to understand this after reading a textbook and comparing with some videos.

Comment: @JoshuaIsralowitz You said " how are the final 'rectangles' graphically not horizontal in the picture provided". Are you talking about the picture provided in my answer or the picture provided in the question?

Comment: My bad, I didn't read your post carefully enough and thus deleted my comment! I don't agree with the sentiment "By the way, the fact that this figure is so wrong that..." though.

To me, the point of this picture is to motivate one possible definition of an extension of the Riemann integral, namely the Lebesgue integral as the Riemann integral of measures of level sets. 

Graphically this should coincide with the Riemann integral when the latter makes sense (it does), while allowing much more nonnegative functions to be integrated (we just need level sets to be measurable!)

Comment: @JoshuaIsralowitz The Lebesgue integral is defined by means of the finite sum $\sum \alpha_i \mu(A_i)$, where $A_i$ is the preimage of $\alpha_i$ under the step function in consideration. In reasonable correct pictures (as the one in my post), $A_i$ is a union of intervals, $\mu(A_i)$ is the sum of the lengths of these intervals and the area $\alpha_i \mu(A_i)$ is clearly seen (the central point being the fact that the same procedure works for a wide variety of cases in which $A_i$ is not geometrically visible).

Comment: @JoshuaIsralowitz In the "wrong picture" provided in the question (horizontal rectangles), what is $\alpha_i$, $A_i$, $\mu(A_i)$ and $\alpha_i\mu(A_i)$? This is a real question. In my view, replacing vertical rectangles with horizontal ones does not motivate the Lebesgue integral, but only illustrates the geometric fact that area is invariant under rigid motion.

Answer (score 4):

The correspondence you are talking about is imaginable in terms of the so-called [*layer-cake decomposition*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation) of a (positive) function as
$$ f(x) = \int_0^{\infty} 1_{\{y:f(y) \geqslant t\}}(x) \, dt $$
This is easy to understand: the function is $1$ until $f(x)=t$, and $0$ thereafter, and
$$ \int_0^{f(x)} \, dt = f(x). $$
Now, consider
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left( \int_0^{\infty} 1_{\{y:f(y) \geqslant t\}}(x) \, dt \right) \, dx  $$
The function here is positive, and (through a Lebesgue integral calculation using [Tonelli's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions)), you can interchange the order of integration to find
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} 1_{\{y:f(y) \geqslant t\}}(x) \, dx \right) \, dt = \int_0^{\infty} \mu\{y: f(y) \geqslant t\} \, dt $$
Now, the integrand of this is a positive, non-increasing function of $t$, so it can be understood as a Riemann integral: in particular, the integrand evaluates the size of the sets on which $f$ is larger than $t$, which you can think of as approximated by horizontal rectangles (the distinction the Lebesgue integral has is that we don't *have* to use rectangles to approximate these sets any more). This integral can then be viewed as going "upwards" along the $y$ axis, the horizontal rectangles of length $\mu\{y: f(y) \geqslant t\}$ being precisely a Riemann sum!

Comment: This is an old post but .... about the last two sentences: it is true that Lebesque integral is "going upwards", but it's misleading or even wrong to call $\mu\{y: f(y) \geqslant t\}$ as "horizontal rectangles". This is propelling the wrong picture of horizontal strips in the color of red cited by OP. The parts described by $\mu\{y: f(y) \geqslant t\}$ are often disconnected (separated) bits when the function is not unimodal.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208024/understanding-layer-cake-representation

Answer (score 0):

Interesting context many don't know about: We can define one-dimensional Lebesgue integral without measure theory at all and using only similar terms Riemann had used — interval partitions and vertical stripes. I am talking about the [McShane integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McShane_integral), which is a nice little modification of the [Henstock-Kurzweil integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock%E2%80%93Kurzweil_integral).

Linked Wikipedia articles are a good start. You can also take a look at *The integrals of Lebesgue, Denjoy, Perron, and Henstock* by Russell Gordon.

Have fun with ∫!