# Understanding Layer Cake Representation

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

It is a common exercise to show that if $f\in L^1 $ then
$$\int_R |f(x)|d\mu(x) =\int_0^\infty \mu(\{|f|\geq t\})dt $$

In showing this, it is common to make the observation that

$$ \mathbb{1}_{[0,|f(x)|]}(t) = \mathbb{1}_{\{|f|\geq t\}}(x) $$

I can't seem to figure out how these are equal and what the notation means. I am familiar with the indicator function, but not of an indicator function being a function of $ t$ or $x$ here, so perhaps this is part of my misunderstanding.

Why are these two indicator functions equal?

Comment: umm, there seem to be issues with weak vs strict inequalities. It should probably read $\mathbf{1}_{[0,|f(x)|)}(t)=\mathbf{1}_{\{|f|>t\}}(x)$. Anyway, can you write out both sides explicitly? When is the LHS equal to $1$? When is the RHS equal to $1$? When is the LHS equal to $0$? When is the RHS equal to $0$?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here $\mathbb{1}_P(t)$ is defined to be

$$\mathbb{1}_P(t) = \begin{cases} 1 & P(t) \text{ is true} \\ 0 & P(t) \text{ is false} \end{cases}$$

When $P$ is a set, like $[0, 3]$, then we look at $t \in P$ instead.

So your two functions are

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{1}_{[0, |f(x)|]}(t) 
&= \begin{cases} 1 & t \in \big [ 0, |f(x)| \big] \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases} \\
&= \begin{cases} 1 & 0 \leq t \leq |f(x)| \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$

$$\mathbb{1}_{|f(x)| \geq t}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & |f(x)| \geq t \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

It should be clear that if we pinky promise to only think about $t \geq 0$, these are actually the same function.

In fact, we can think of this as *one* function, taking $x$ and $t$ as inputs, call it $\mathsf{blah}(x,t)$. Then our first function is what we get when we fix an $x$ and view this as a function of $t$, and our second function is what we get if we fix a $t$ and view it as a function of $x$. That is:

$$\mathbb{1}_{[0, |f(x)|]}(t) = \mathsf{blah}(x,t) = \mathbb{1}_{|f(x)| \geq t}(x)$$

Now, what happens if we *integrate* these functions?

Well,

$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[0, |f(x)|]}(t) dt = |f(x)|$$

and

$$\int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{|f(x)| \geq t}(x) d \mu (x) = \mu \left ( \{ x \mid |f(x)| \geq t \} \right )$$

(in each case, do you see why?).

Now the integral identity you're asking about is more or less [fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). We have two variables of interest, and we can integrate in either order!

So we have

$$
\int_0^\infty |f(x)| d \mu(x) 
= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[0, |f(x)|]}(t) dt d \mu(x)
\overset{\star}{=} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{|f(x)| \geq t}(x) d \mu (x) dt
= \int_0^\infty \mu \left ( \{ x \mid |f(x)| \geq t \} \right ) dt
$$

where in step $\star$ we used the ideas from earlier in this answer, plus fubini's theorem.

---

I hope this helps ^_^