# Lebesgue integral notation confusion - is $dt$ implicitly w.r.t Lebesgue?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

In theorems such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208024/understanding-layer-cake-representation), there appears one integral w.r.t $t$, using $dt$ and another w.r.t $x$ using $d\mu (x)$. Should I take the fact that $t$ has no explicit measure assigned to it to mean that $dt$ is w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure, and that since $x$ *does* have an explicit measure to it, then it is a general measure? How should one read these notations?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, $dt$ refers to Lebesgue measure.

Comment: $\mathrm{d}t$ is the Lebesgue-measure beacuse there we are in a measure theory environment. Often $\mathrm{d}t$ is a Riemann-Integral. The difference is not that massive.

Comment: The answer is not just "yes" but needs an expletive too.  How can a notation $\int f(x)\,dx$ from 1684 about little-understood derivatives survive so long that Lebesgue preserved it for his integration theory in 1901 and it is used now even for integration in abstract measure spaces?