# Understanding Layer Cake Representation for $f\in L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

The closest post I found was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208024/understanding-layer-cake-representation) but it's not for $L^p$ and I don't see how to extend it. I'm trying to formally see why the following holds too:

$$|f(x)|^p=\int_0^{f(x)}pa^{p-1}da$$

Initially I thought it has something to do with Riemann being equal to the Lebesgue integral here perhaps ($da$ is w.r.t. Lebesgue), but I'm not seeing it.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: You can just do the integral.

Comment: I suppose I could if I claim that $pa^{p-1}$ is continuous and bounded in $[0,f(x)]$ to justify it is Riemann integrable. I guess there is no issue with that.

Comment: This is elementary calculus. If you’re not willing to assume the function $x \mapsto x^p$ is continuous, you should know how to prove it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Think I got it:

Denote $g(x):=f(x)^p$.

Then by the Layer Cake Representation for $L^1$ we have:

$$g(x) = \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{x|g(x) > t\}}dt$$

which means:

$$f(x)^p = \int_0^\infty \chi_{\{x|f(x)^p > t\}}dt$$

Now by change of variables, we can obtain:

$$f(x)^p = \int_0^\infty pa^{p-1}\chi_{\{x|f(x)^p > a^p\}}da = \int_0^\infty pa^{p-1}\chi_{\{x|f(x) > a\}}da = \int_0^{f(x)} pa^{p-1}da$$